# Python class property update not propagating to parent class

Tags: python

When I update an instance property, that change is not reflected in the `__str__` method of the parent class. This makes sense, as `super().__init__` is called during the `__init__` call, and when I make an update to the property, it's not getting called again.

```py
class BulkData:
    def __init__(self, fields):
        self.fields = fields

    def __str__(self):
        return ''.join(str(f) for f in self.fields)

class Node(BulkData):
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z
        fields = [self.x, self.y, self.z]
        super().__init__(fields)
```

Example:

```py
n1 = Node(1,2,3)
n1.x = 5
print(n1)
> '123'
```

I would like the result to be `'523'`.

Comment: You changed `x` but not `fields`... Please read about [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). You can also use [Python-Tutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) which helps to visualize the execution of the code step-by-step.

Comment: `fields` is a list initialized from the *values* of `x`, `y`, and `z`; it is not otherwise related to the `Node` attributes.

Comment: Also, in this case the code's simple enough we can tell what you mean, but please keep in mind that it's a good idea to test your code first and make sure it actually does what you think it does before posting it here. Even after fixing the indentation, this will throw an exception when trying to reference `floats`, and `print(Node)` is not `print(n1)`.

Answer (score 2):

You mention in your question *"property"* but those are just attributes. One way to achieve that is to actually use a [`property`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17330160/how-does-the-property-decorator-work-in-python):

```py
class BulkData:
    def __init__(self, fields):
        self.fields = fields

    def __str__(self):
        return ''.join(self.fields)

class Node(BulkData):
        def __init__(self, x, y, z):
            self._x = x
            self._y = y
            self._z = z
            fields = [self._x, self._y, self._z]
            super().__init__(fields)

        @property
        def x(self):
            return self._x

        @x.setter
        def x(self, val):
            self._x = val
            self.fields[0] = val
```

And now:

```
>>> n1 = Node('1','2','3')
>>> n1.x = '5'
>>> print(n1)
523
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define *actual* Python properties that reflect the state of `fields`:

```
class BulkData:
    def __init__(self, fields, floats=None):
        if floats is None:
            floats = []
        self.fields = fields
        self.floats = floats
    
    def __str__(self):
        return ''.join([str(x) for x in self.fields])

class Node(BulkData):
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        super().__init__([x, y, z])

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self.fields[0]

    @x.setter(self, v):
        self.fields[0] = v

    @property
    def y(self):
        return self.fields[1]

    @y.setter(self, v):
        self.fields[1] = v

    @property
    def z(self):
        return self.fields[2]

    @z.setter(self, v):
        self.fields[2] = v
```

Instead of instance attributes, you define `property` instances that "wrap" a particular slot of the underlying `fields` attribute.

---

If you are thinking, that's a lot of code... you're right. Let's fix that.

```
class FieldReference(property):
    def __init__(self, pos):
        def getter(self):
            return self.fields[pos]

        def setter(self, v):
            self.fields[pos] = v

        super().__init__(getter, setter)


class Node(BulkData):
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        super().__init__([x, y, z])

    x = FieldReference(0)
    y = FieldReference(1)
    z = FieldReference(2)
```

Here, we subclass `property` and hard-code the getter and setter functions to operate on the position specified by the argument to the property. Note that `self` in `getter` and `setter` are distinct from `self` in `__init__`, but `getter` and `setter` are both closures with access to `__init__`'s argument `pos`.

You might also want to read the [Descriptor how-to](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html), specifically the section on [properties](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#properties) to understand why `FieldReference` is defined the way it is.

Comment: Slick! But what's the `None` in  `Node`'s call to  `super().__init__`? (Also keep in mind that `floats` is undefined, and that `str.join` will fail on integers. I know it was the same way in OP's code, but still.)

Comment: Oh, I just stuck something in there to make sure the code ran. It should presumably be whatever hard-coded value you want for the `floats` attribute defined in `BulkData.__init__`.

Comment: I also forgot to update the answer to make sure `join` got a list of strings; will fix.